# Artifactory Jenkins Plugin

Tags: jenkins, rpm, artifactory

I'm using the Artifactory plugin for my Java projects and also for some RPMs that I'm building (c++).
Some of Jenkins jobs are pushing artifacts using the `REST API` via `CURL`.
Is there any way via the plugin and/or via REST, to prevent overriding of an existing artifact (sometimes our versioning mechanism is not working properly, so I need to prevent this scenario)?

Answer (score 1):

You should leverage the permissions for that. In Artifactory "add" and "override" are different permissions. Just prevent the user which pushes from Jenkins from overriding, and you're done.

Comment: Baruch, thanks for the quick response!
I'm using Artifactory 3.5.1, I'm looking in the users page, i can find "add" or "override" permissions over there, I can see only: Manage, Delete, Deploy, Annotate and Read. Is it supported in 3.5.1 ?

Comment: @user3502786 the delete permission is the one required for overwriting